# styleUrls - Not able to load the css style sheet for the component using relative path in angular 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-components

I have a "Hero" component defined under "app/Hero" in angular 2. The hero component as "hero.component.html","hero.component.css" and "hero.component.ts" files defined. the templateUrl works fine but the styleUrls do not load. Resource not found error will be displayed. I referred this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#relative-urls to load styles using relative URLs.

```
  @Component({
  providers: [HeroService],
  templateUrl: './Hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Hero.component.css'],
})
```

Comment: Remove the las comma. css'], and use lower case for the Hero

Comment: Please add your folder structure with file names

Comment: @kimy82 I removed the last comma. But still I get error : Failed to load resource.

Comment: Yeah I think you might have to set the  selector  _selector: 'hero-component',_ and move the providers to the app.module.ts . Make sure you are not using less instead of css files

Answer (score 0):

Check out the filename and make sure you type it correctly. It could be case sensitive! Also make sure you follow the correct folder structure.

If you have the following in your component declaration

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css'],
})
```

your folder hierarchy should look like this:

```
app.module.ts
hero
- hero.component.ts
- hero.component.css
- hero.component.html
```

Comment: @user1731770 I edited the solution with a sample folder structure that is working for me. Does it work now?

Comment: I have same folder structure. It shows the same error. Failed to load the resource. I have not mentioned selector in the component.

Comment: @user1731770 it certainly does not only work with absolute paths. the selector is not relevant. Try creating the project with the angular-cli. It will definitley work that way and both folder structure and component settings will be perfectly set.

Comment: I know it's sound crazy. But I have an Ionic/Angular 2 project, and it seems that the absolute path is working :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
styles: [require('./app.component.css').toString()]
```

And you have to change webpack.config.js. Instead of 'raw-loader' you have to specify the next:

```
loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
```