# How to ovveride the css class of root component in its child component - Angular 2?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components

I have 3 components in angular 2 application.The `class="container-fluid content"` is css class in app.component.html. This `class="container-fluid content"` is default css for other components. Now I want to set `background-color:blue` in the detail component. I tried to set in detail.component.ts like this `styles:['.container-fluid content{background-color: blue;}']` It did not work. If I set in app.component.html like this `<div class="container-fluid content" style="background-color: blue;">` It applies to both the components. How to override this class="container-fluid content" in detail component?

```
 //my project structure

app
  - app.component.html
  -app.component.ts
- welcome
  -welcome.component.html
  -welcome.component.ts
- detail
  -detail.component.html
  -detail.component.ts

//app.component.html
<div class="container-fluid content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>

//welcome.component.html
<h1>welcome page heading</h1>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap  style="padding-bottom: 25px; 
 padding-top: 25px;  margin: auto;justify-content: center" >  
<md-card>
          <md-card-content>
            <h1></h1>
            <h2></h2>
          <h2>
            </h2>
          </md-card-content>
          </md-card> 
        </div>

//detail.component.html
<h1>Details page heading</h1>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap  style="padding-bottom: 25px; 
 padding-top: 25px;  margin: auto;justify-content: center" >  
<md-card>
          <md-card-content>
            <h1></h1>
            <h2></h2>
          <h2>
            </h2>
          </md-card-content>
          </md-card> 
        </div>
//detail.component.ts
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DetailService } from '../detail/detail.service'; 
import { HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  providers: [DetailService ]
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styles: ['h3 {margin:5px}'] 

})

export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

 @HostBinding('class.blueClass') blue: boolean = false;

  constructor( private _detailService: DetailService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

this.blue = true;
}
}
```

Comment: It can be fine if you show up how the detail.component.ts works.

Comment: @tildy Please find the sample code of detail.component.ts above

Answer (score 4):

In child component, you can add this param to `@Component`.

```
// child-component.component.ts
    
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: 'child-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['child-component.component.css']
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

```
// child-component.component.css

.container-fluid content{background-color: blue;}
```

You can ref this side for more infomartion :

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: I get error failed to load resource 'child-component.component.css'

Comment: Can you give detail error, folder structure, build tool ?

Comment: have you created the css for it? In your structure it should be here:

 - detail
  -detail.component.html
  -detail.component.ts
-detail.component.css, and you should use styleUrls: ['detail.component.css']

Comment: Yes, I did the same way. In Chrome browser console I get this error `Failed to load resource: :8100/detail.component.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load detail.component.css ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load detail.component.css undefined
consoleError @ zone.js:522
zone.js:524 ZoneAwareError
consoleError @ zone.js:524`

Comment: Try with this way: `styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.css']`

Comment: It did not work again. I had this issue before and could'nt resolve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851295/styleurls-not-able-to-load-the-css-style-sheet-for-the-component-using-relativ

Comment: @ThienHoang Hi, I gave absolute path to load the css style sheet in styleUrls. I did exactly same way as metioned above in your code example except that i dont have selector in my component. But now the background color is applied for both components. I want it only to apply for the detail component.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the hostbinding and adding a new class there?

```
 @HostBinding('class.blueClass') blue: boolean = false;
```

And in the second component just switch that on onInit?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.blue = true;
}
```

The other way could be in the component definition, you can add the following line :

```
  host: {'class': 'blueClass'}
```

and you do the rest of the css work in css instead.

Comment: where do I need to add this  @HostBinding('class.someClass') blue: boolean = false;. In which component?

Comment: add in your detail.component.ts file. Import HostBinding decorator from angular/core

Comment: In the detail component.

Comment: Did you add the HostBinding into the import ?

import {Component, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';